# How to add a constant string into an array of strings at given position

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

> I want to add a const string like "d'Artagnan" into an array of 8 strings { "Duke of Buckingham" , "Porthos", "Athos", "Aramis", "Planchet", "Monsieur de Treville", "Mousqueton", "Kitty"} after the string "Aramis". But when it runs, the string after "d'Artagnan" is also "d'Artagnan"
> This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//function to add constant string
char addString(char *a[100], int *n, const char *s, int pos) {
for (int i = (*n); i > pos; i--) {
        a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    strcpy(a[pos], s);  
    (*n)++;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    char *a[100], s1[10];
    strcpy(s1, "Aramis");

    // allocate array of strings and get input
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(a[i], 100, stdin);
    strtok(a[i], "\n");
    }

    //add string "d'Artagnan" after string "Aramis" 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(a[i-1], s1) == 0) {
            addString(a, &n, "d'Artagnan", i);
        }
    }

    //Print output
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%s ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: Do u know how to solve it in C?

Comment: What does the array that you pass to `addString` look like? How do you call `addString`. At first glance, it seems that you should copy the pointers and allocate space for (or `strdup`) the new string.

Comment: @NguyễnHà That's not the point. If this is a pure C program, remove the C++ tag. Also, the error of `it's wrong and idk why` is not valid. Give a more detailed description of what has failed.

Comment: Please edit your question, where it belongs. Long stretches of code in comments are not very readable.

Comment: I want to add a const string like "d'Artagnan" into an array of 8 strings { "Duke of Buckingham" , "Porthos", "Athos", "Aramis", "Planchet",  "Monsieur de Treville", "Mousqueton", "Kitty"} after the string "Aramis". But when it runs, the string after  "d'Artagnan" is also  "d'Artagnan" .

Comment: As MOehm  said, please **edit** your question. Having all the details in the comment section is pointless.

Comment: There are different ways to find bugs in code at this point.  You can run it under a debugger, and watch what the sequence the code executes and how the variables change.  You can also "walk through" the code in your head.  With this approach, the first thing you'll presumably need to do is put the first string in the array, so your first call will be something like `addString(&somearray, &size /* 0 */, "some string", 0)`.  With `*n == 0` and `pos == 0`, contemplate what `strcpy` is targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it another way:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    char *names[];
}names_t;

names_t *addString(names_t *a, const char *s, size_t pos) 
{
    size_t newsize = a ? a -> size + 1 : 1;

    if(pos < newsize)
    {
        a = realloc(a, sizeof(*a) + newsize * sizeof(a -> names[0]));
        if(a)
        {
            a -> size = newsize;
            memmove(&a -> names[pos + 1], &a -> names[pos], sizeof(a -> names[0]) * (a -> size - pos - 1));
            if((a -> names[pos] = malloc(strlen(s) + 1)))
            {
                strcpy(a -> names[pos], s);
            }
            else
            {
                free(a);
                a = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        a = NULL;
    return a;
}
```

Your structure will grow when you add strings. No need to preallocate a fixed-size array. It will also allocate memory for the copy of the string (you can also use `strdup` for that, I did not, to show how to allocate the exact memory needed for the string).